# A better way to detect a change in a parse class?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, traffic

Currently I set up a timer that every 2 seconds makes a query to a parse class to see if any data has changed. If the data has changed it calls the `refreshData` method so my view can be updated with the new parse data. 
So when ever data is updated in the parse class it will almost instantly be updated in the app.

The problem is this causes a lot of unnecessary web traffic, which I need to avoid.

What can I do to replace the timer with something that detects when data is changed in the parse class then tells the app to call the `refreshData` method?

Comment: You should use afterSave cloud code to send a push notification

Comment: @Paulw11 Could I please have an example of this?

Comment: Have a read through the Parse docs on Cloud Code and their javascript libraries.  They have samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**afterSave Triggers**

```
    //this will trigger everytime the className objects has changed
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("className", function(request) {
    //Do some stuff here //like calling http request or sending push 'data has changed' to installed mobile device
        console.log("Object has been added/updated"+request.object.id);

});
```

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers

**You need to deploy first a cloud code then it will handle your problem :-)**

In some cases, you may want to perform some action, such as a push, after an object has been saved. You can do this by registering a handler with the afterSave method. For example, suppose you want to keep track of the number of comments on a blog post. You can do that by writing a function like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Comment", function(request) {
  query = new Parse.Query("Post");
  query.get(request.object.get("post").id, {
    success: function(post) {
      post.increment("comments");
      post.save();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

The client will receive a successful response to the save request after the handler terminates, regardless of how it terminates. For instance, the client will receive a successful response even if the handler throws an exception. Any errors that occurred while running the handler can be found in the Cloud Code log.

If you want to use afterSave for a predefined class in the Parse JavaScript SDK (e.g. Parse.User), you should not pass a String for the first argument. Instead, you should pass the class itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I still don't understand, say the cloud code is called to send a push notification, how will the other applications receive the push notification so it knows to call a method?

Comment: First deploy a cloud code that has aftersave methods. after that see the instruction here on how to create an app that can receive push notifications http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/ then create push notification trigger in cloud code

Comment: Are the "push notifications" the ones that pop up on your lock screen? because I don't want that. I want my app to be notified behind the scenes if you understand? so the user doesn't even know the app received a push notification.

Comment: you have the choice if you want to show popup or do  it directly depends on your preference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if my solution will fit with your needs, but using `beforeSave` trigger within **CloudCode**, combined to **DirtyKeys** will save you time and queries : http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-objects-dirtykeys/

With **DirtyKeys** you can detect once some change was done on your class, and then you can build new trigger and do whatever you need once done.